# Can I get a list of media files duration using something like DIR?

Tags: windows, filesystems, dir

I'm at folder Music, all right? and let's say I want to know the name and other attributes of every song in that directory, then I'll just open a terminal and go

> dir > musicFiles.txt

but that wouldn't give me the files duration.
Can it be done similarly getting that information? I already checked DIR's parameters and couldn't find one that works with this field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command line tool like exiftool:

```
exiftool -ext mp3 -p "$Filename $Duration" .
```

[image]

- To get the duration without the (approx) in the end:

  ```
  exiftool *.mp3 -p "$Filename - ${duration;s/ \(.*//}"
  ```

Or maybe try the powershell solution from this link:

[PowerShell Get video duration and list all files recursively, export to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830853/powershell-get-video-duration-and-list-all-files-recursively-export-to-csv)